# Objective - C Sting formatting just like printf/NSString stringWithFormat

Tags: objective-c, ios, string, numbers, format

I'm using a commercial third party library that is very restrictive of the formatting of numbers displayed on the screen.

the formating can only done by You can customising a String called `labelFormatString` on each series, for example:

```
donutSeries.labelFormatString = @"$%.02f";
```

just like `printf/NSString stringWithFormat`.

and of course now my requirements impose me one final tweak that I can't figure out 
instead of being display `$123456789` I have to display them `$123,456,789`

Is if possible to achieve this using ONLY the string mentioned above and NOTHING ELSE (no `NSNumberFormater` etc).

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 2):

@zahreelay He said without formatters as he can't use them. What I think it's not possible, because formatting depends on locale and some other stuff and obj-c string formatting is not exactly the same as printf's formatting specifications. Even with printf to make thousand separation work you have to set some locale:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
unsigned int x = 12345u;
printf("%'8u\n", x); //prints 12,345
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work with NSLog for ex. (just tested it)

Comment: Yes, Apple's own docs ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)) mention the IEEE specs ([here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html)), so I think the issue even would warrant a bug report.

Comment: Actually the magic in this example is calling 'setlocale' function and the **'** symbol in the formatter, which symbol is marked as an extension to the ISO C standard in the IEEE specifications, so it's very possible that Apple have omitted these extensions and implemented them with their formatters...

Answer (score -1):

Look at the NSNumberFormatter class , i believe, you could achieve it using that.

e.g.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // this line is important!

NSString *formatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:2000000]]

[formatter release];
```

Comment: and I beleive you didn't read my question... I can't use NSNumberFormater in this case because the framework doesn't allow me too.